# Display Two Images

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uiimagepickercontroller

using two UIImageview And two button when tap a first button image picker let you chose image

from photo library and same to the second button. this is what i did

viewcontroler.h

```
UIImagePickerController *pic1;
UIImagePickerController *pic2;
UIImage *image1;
UIImage *image2;

IBOutlet UIImageView *imageview1;
IBOutlet UIImageView *imageview2;

-(IBAction)Load1:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)Load2:(id)sender;
```

vewcontroller.m

```
  -(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{

   image1 = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
   image2 = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
   [imageview1 setImage:image1];
   [imageview2 setImage:image2];


   [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];

}


-(void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
{
   [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}


- (IBAction)Load1:(id)sender
{
   pic1 = [[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];
   pic1.delegate = self;
   [pic1 setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary];
   [self presentViewController:pic1 animated:YES completion:NULL];
}

- (IBAction)Load2:(id)sender
{
   pic2 = [[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];
   pic2.delegate = self;
   [pic2 setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary];
   [self presentViewController:pic2 animated:YES completion:NULL];


}
```

when i run. the first button work. let you chose the image from photo library and   display it, 
the second button work as will but the image you chose display in both UIImageview

what i did wrong here,
thanks

Answer (score 1):

These lines are causing both imageviews to have a same image that you select:

```
image1 = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
image2 = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
```

Both imageviews are having the same source image as : `UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage` in :

`-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info`

What you need to do is to differentiate which button was pressed and in which imageview that image should be contained. Ofcourse many approaches could be followed: like you can use some bool to differentiate the caller like:

```
 -(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
   if (button1Clicked)   //Boolean to determine which button was pressed, set it in IBAction of the button
   {
      image1 = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
      [imageview1 setImage:image1];
   }
   else
   {
      image2 = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
      [imageview2 setImage:image2];
   }

      [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];

}
```

or any other relevant approach.

Comment: @Amir: you are welcome, you should Mark this answer as "Accepted" if it has solved your issue.

Comment: i try it but still have the problam i add boolean Load1Clicked; in view controller.h

Comment: @Amir: i expect that you must had understood the issue which is causing inconsistency. Having a flag set to determine which button action triggered the UIImagePicker's delegate, you can easily sort out this issue now.

Comment: @Amir: Debug your code and you are definately gonna find the issue